# Using a substitution of a square of a trigonometric function.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Are there any cases where we could use a substitution, for example, $x=\tan^2(\theta)$? If so, how would one go about it? I tried to solve a simple integral $\int \sqrt{x-1}dx $ with the substitution $x=\sec^2{\theta}$. However, i ended up with $2/3\tan^3{\theta}$ which i have no idea how to transform back to $x$ except getting $2/3\tan{\theta}(x-1)$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you not want to use a u-substitution?

Comment: @aleden I am wondering if this kind of inverse substitution is ever used. And if so, how would one proceed.

Comment: You certainly can, but you're making easy things difficult.

Comment: @egreg I think he want just to test the method in a simple case

Comment: @gimusi I don't think there is a case where such a substitution simplifies things.

Comment: @Sorfosh If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Sorfosh Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1):

If you have $x=\sec^2(\theta)$ then $\tan(\theta)=\sqrt{x-1}$ or its negative and thus on the positive side $$\tfrac23 \tan^3(\theta)=\tfrac23 (x-1)^{3/2}$$ Indeed  $$\int \sqrt{x-1}\,dx = \tfrac23 (x-1)^{3/2} +C$$ so your method works, though you do not really need substitution for this

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$x=\sec^2{\theta} \implies dx =2 \tan\theta \sec^2 \theta \,d\theta$$

$$\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{\sec^2{\theta}-1}=\tan \theta$$

$$\int \sqrt{x-1}dx=2\int \tan^2\theta\sec^2 \theta \,d\theta=\frac23\tan^3\theta$$

and

$$\tan(\arccos x)  =\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x}$$

$$\theta=\arccos \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$

we have that

$$\int \sqrt{x-1}dx=\frac23\tan^3\theta=\frac23 \left(\frac{\sqrt{1 - \frac1x}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt x}}\right)^3=\frac23(x-1)^\frac32$$

Comment: how did you know to choose $+\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: the original integral is for a not negative function, thus I think that it is the correct choose $+\sqrt{x}$